# Oracle Sql Statement for unique timestamp for each row

Tags: sql, oracle

We have following table on an Oracle DBMS (used by a legacy application), where a timestamp is part of the key (I know there would be better ways...)

```
TABLE ITEM_HISTORY (
 ITEM_ID number,
 MY_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(7),
 ... 
 PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_ID, MY_TIMESTAMP));
```

Only the combination of ITEM_ID and MY_TIMESTAMP is unique. On a running system
we need to guarantee now, that every timestamp is unique, because we have to make 
some corrections of corrupt data and with given data we violate the unique key constraint. 
With a simple MY_TIMESTAMP = SYSTEMTIMESTAMP update, all rows 
will have the same timestamp.

How can I update my Table with SQL, so that every row has an unique timestamp?

**Update / Explanation:**

Because data got corrupted at our client, I only can try to correct the items as good as possible.
In some cases, items (with different ITEM_IDs) in the corrupted table will be corrected
to the same item with same ITEM_ID. To make this update, I must guarantee before that the
timestamps are different.

Comment: A few thoughts. 1 - What if 2 rows were inserted at the exact same time (i know they would be milliseconds apart) but what if the timestamp isnt that precise?  2 - You would have to reload/insert all the data.  There's no way to handle the records that are already in the table. 3 - Is there any other sort of unique identifier you could build? Possibly an `auto-increment`?  I'm coming from sql land and am not intimately familiar with Oracle.

Comment: Can you clarify which DBMS you are using?  Is it SQL or Oracle?

Comment: Add a sequence for the unique key.  Why would you want to use a timestamp for this purpose anyway?  You run the risk that future data will violate the constraint.

Comment: What is TABLE_ID? Can it change? Why don't focus on that?

Comment: I agree with the comments, that the table is not well designed. I can't change that. The table is live at customer and they faced a problem, because they imported invalid data. By correcting the data I faced the problem, that many timestamps have the exact same value. And I run into the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `UPDATE` statement will guarantee that each row has a unique `MY_TIMESTAMP` value, by increasing the milliseconds by the rownum value.

**EDIT**:
*After Alessandro Rossi pointed out that there could be duplicate values, the following query has been modified to use SYSTIMESTAMP for the update.*

```
  UPDATE ITEM_HISTORY 
  SET my_timestamp = SYSTIMESTAMP + NUMTODSINTERVAL(rownum/1000, 'SECOND');
```

However, it is recommended that you use an alternative strategy, such as adding another column to store the key value.

Comment: Not a good answer at all!!!! How could this work? Two duplicates will both be increased by 1 millisecond. They will still be duplicates, with the difference to have a wrong value now!!

Comment: @AlessandroRossi Did you try running some tests? The rownum will be unique for each row, and therefore the increment to even the same MY_TIMESTAMP values will be different.

Comment: Anyway: if row #1 has value 0.002 and row #2 has value 0.001 after the UPDATE they be duplicates, if table has 100000000 rows on row #100000000 the value is totally out of control. Hope to be clear this UPDATE is to avoid at all: it can change important values (imagine Formula1 lap times at Monte Carlo) and it can create new duplicates

Comment: @AlessandroRossi I think you may have a point there. I'll change the query to use SYSTIMESTAMP. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think that the timestamp should not be changed because it has a meaning. It shouldn't be part of the Primary key and the focus of uniqueness should be moved to other directions. The OP should also explain why he's concentrated only on the timestamp column!

Comment: @AlessandroRossi I updated the question and explained, why I have to do it in this form. I hope it is understandable.