# MySQL Update multiple rows with unique timestamp per row

Tags: mysql

For e.g. I have a table named `people` with the following columns-

```
people_id (primary key, auto inc)
first_name
last_name
timestamp (default - current_timestamp)
```

This table already had 30,000 rows before the last column `timestamp` was added, so at present all the timestamps are the same. I want each timestamp to be unique, but I am unable to do so.

Closest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428250/2587662) on stackoverflow I could found, is of Oracle, which suggests the following query -

```
UPDATE ITEM_HISTORY SET my_timestamp = SYSTIMESTAMP + NUMTODSINTERVAL(rownum/1000, 'SECOND');
```

But this query does not work in MySQL, because there are no such functions for `NUMTODSINTERVAL` and `SYSTIMESTAMP`. I tried to use above mentioned query as -

```
UPDATE people SET `timestamp` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + people_id;
```

But it failed, I think because, people_id (int) can't be added to timestamp. **So is there any way to convert and add the people_id in timestamp or any other way to update rows with unique timestamps?**

Thanks.

Comment: `UPDATE people SET \`timestamp\` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL people_id MINUTE;`

Comment: Requiring timestamps to be unique seems like a very bad criterion, and one that is bound to cause significant headaches further down the line.  Look again at your requirements.

Comment: @eggyal Yes, I read the same about it on the linked SO answer. But, I just just need them to be unique to push the newly updated rows to android app (and for the first run of pushing this update was causing problem, because all 30K rows had same timestamps), I was earlier going with Unique/Primary Id only, but then I couldn't push latest updated rows. Can you suggest any alternate for this? Thanks,

Comment: You haven't provided any explanation of why the push didn't work when the timestamps were all the same—something that will be a property of your application, about which I know nothing.  Perhaps ask a question about that instead?

Comment: @eggyal Your question made me think of my requirements again. I will go through it, without using timestamps, and will ask separate question, if needed any help. Thanks for your mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some second using interval based on your user's id

```
    UPDATE people SET `timestamp` = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , INTERVAL `id` SECOND);
```

[Read more here about DATE_ADD() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime)

Comment: It worked. Thanks for both answer and link of the function. I will accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow timelimit allows me.

Answer (score 0):

> But it failed, I think because, people_id (int) can't be added to timestamp

Sure it can.  you could use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

```
UPDATE people SET timestamp = DATE_ADD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL id SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me
    UPDATE people SET `timestamp` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()  + people_id;